# How to export environment variable on remote host with GitlabCI

Tags: laravel, deployment, gitlab-ci, devops

I'm using GitlabCI to deploy my Laravel applications.
I'm wondering how should I manage the `.env` file. As far as I've understood I just need to put the `.env.example` under version control and not the one with the real values.

I've set all the keys my app needs inside Gitlab `Settings -> CI/CD -> Environment Variables` and I can use them on the runner, for example to retrieve the SSH private key to connect to the remote host, but how should I deploy these variables to the remote host as well? Should I write them with bash in a "runtime generated" `.env` file and then copy it? Should I export them via ssh on the remote host? Which is the correct way to manage this?

Comment: you use a tool to deploy like  Fabric - Ansible - Puppet on your gitlab CI/CD  ? 
Or you use just an ssh command and pull inside de server ?

Comment: @SeddikOmar, I usually ssh in the server and then pull the code. But I'm open to better solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open to another solution i propose using fabric(fabfile) i give you an example:
create .env.default with variable like :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=%(HOST)s
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=%(USER)s
DB_PASSWORD=%(PASSWORD)s
```

After installing fabric add fabfile on you project directory:

```
from fabric.api import env , run , put


prod_env = {
  'name' : 'prod' ,
  'user' : 'user_ssh',
  'deploy_to' : '/path_to_project',
  'hosts' : ['ip_server'],
}

def set_config(env_config):
  for key in env_config:
     env[key] = env_config[key]

def prod():
  set_config(prod_env)


def deploy(password,host,user):
  run("cd %s && git pull -r",env.deploy_to)
  process_template(".env.default",".env" , { 'PASSWORD' : password , 'HOST' : host,'USER': user } )
  put( ".env" , "/path_to_projet/.env" )


def process_template(template , output , context ):
  import os
  basename = os.path.basename(template)
  output = open(output, "w+b")
  text = None

  with open(template) as inputfile:
    text = inputfile.read()

  if context:
    text = text % context
  #print " processed \n : %s" % text
  output.write(text)
  output.close()
```

Now you can run from you local to test script :

> fab prod deploy:password="pass",user="user",host="host"

It will deploy project on your server and check if it process .env

If **it works** now it's time for gitlab ci this is an example file :

```
image: python:2.7
before_script:
  - pip install 'fabric<2.0'
  # Setup SSH deploy keys
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

deploy_staging:
  type: deploy
  script:
     - fab prod deploy:password="$PASSWORD",user="$USER",host="$HOST"
 only:
     - master
```

$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY,$PASSWORD,$USER,$HOST is environnement variable gitlab,you should add a $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY private key which have access to the server.

Hope i don't miss a step.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it out!