# Gitlab CI with Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to implement gitlab CI for one of our drupal projects. For example: When a developer pushes the code to the repo in gitlab automatic tests should run using the gitlab CI pipeline which tests the code and notifies whether the code quality is fine enough to update the code to the repo. If else the developer needs to correct the coding standards and issues reported. I have tried different combination of `gitlab-ci.yml` file with less success.

Can anyone mention a sample `gitlab-ci.yml` file which can be used for drupal Projects which will trigger the CI pipeline and also run the tests using the gitlab runner so I could build upon that? I have already read through the gitlab-ci documentation.

Comment: Refer to my response here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56675848/how-to-export-environment-variable-on-remote-host-with-gitlabci/56777419] it will be a start for what you would like to do. Laravel in my exemple use **.env** on drupal you should use  **settings.php**.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the GitLab provided [PHP template](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/PHP.gitlab-ci.yml). This will get you into a docker image with PHP, xdebug, and your project composer installed.

As configured the template expects your project to have a phpunit.xml file in the root directory.